# Error on Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, php

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/exc/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

I am receiving this error on my Magento 1 store... I tried increasing Memory limit and that did not work. Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you increase your limit? What is your web server environment (apache/nginx)? This is a PHP/web service issue and not a Magento issue. Magento dev docs would tell you to edit the `.htaccess` file if using Apache, where `php_value` directive is present. However, some web servers are configured to disallow that, or else it is being overwritten in some other way. "tried to allocate 32 bytes" seems like a larger problem (maybe you are using a VM with low memory allocated?).

Comment: What were you doing at the time? Reindex/Cache Delete/Nothing?

Comment: I was deleting cache and after that I received the error.